# Splitting file while reading

Tags: java, split, resources, printwriter

I have a very large file, which I must read and separate it (depending on the first character of the line) into other files that will then be processed for another process.
The problem is: Sometimes, one of the types is absurdly large and we would need to "split" it,
so there will be N subfiles.

I cannot remap the PrintWriter with a try-with-resources, I am doing the following.
I manage the file that is "OK" with the try-with-resources and the other one I manage dynamically:

```
 try PrintWriter printerFile2 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2))) {
        
    PrintWriter printerFile1= new PrintWriter (new FileWriter(String.format("%s.%02d", file1, part)));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.startsWith("A")) {
            type = line.charAt(1);
            doStuffA(type);
                            count++;
            printerFile1 = decidePartFile(file1,Constants.MAX_LINES_AB, printerFile1);
            printerFile1.print(line+"\n");
        } else if (line.startsWith("B")) {
            type = line.charAt(1);
            doStuffB(type);
                            count++;
            printerFile1 = decidePartFile(file1,Constants.MAX_LINES_AB, printerFile1);
            printerFile1.print(line+"\n");
        } else if (line.startsWith("C")) {
            type = line.charAt(1);
            doStuffC(type);
            printerFile2 .print(line + "\n");
        } else if (line.startsWith("D")) {
            type = line.charAt(1);
            doStuffD(type);
            printerFile2 .print(line + "\n");
        } 

            printerFile1.close();
  }
```

the decidePartFile() method

```
private PrintWriter decidePartFile (String file,int limit, PrintWriter originalPrintWriter) throws IOException{
    if (count == limit){
        part++;
        count= 0;
        originalPrintWriter.close();
        String filePartName= String.format("%s.%02d", file1, part
        PrintWriter newPrinter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filePartName));
        return newPrinter;          
    } else {
        return originalPrintWriter;
    }
}
```

When the limit is reached and the PrintWriter is changed, initially the original is closed and the next one is returned, reassigning it
If it has not reached the limit it remains as it is.

I'm afraid that this way the PrintWriters are not closing properly when they are reassigned.
Are they closing properly, or are they left open?

Also, it seems like a very ugly solution to me, I don't know if anyone has a better solution. I can't read the original file again :(

Answer (score 2):

It's generally best to redesign your code so that you have a simple try-with-resource on any autocloseable.  Using try-with-resource guarantees you don't leak memory.   Superficially, you have dealt with the close, but, I'd give you negative marks because you will leak under exceptional conditions.

So...  how should you redesign so you can do try-with-resource always?  Well, simplest is to be more atomic.  Open-the-file/read-character/close-file.  Then kick the filename into whatever queue is appropriate.  Whatever processes that queue operates on a file name, opens the file, does stuff, closes the file.   Never pass around an open file.

Comment: Thank you Jeff! I did something like this and looks cleaner, with the try-with-resources block.